# Считать информацию из файла

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
 
struct Table{
    char fullname [100];
    int group;
    int firstMarks[5];
    int secondMarks[5];
};
 
void ReadTable (Table *&data, int N);
 
 
int main() {
 
    int N = 5;
    Table *data = new Table[N]{
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {}
 
    };
 
    ReadTable(data, N);
 
 
}
 
 
void ReadTable (Table *&data, int N){
 
    FILE *fl = fopen("table.txt","r");
 
    if (!fl) {
        cout << "Помилка";
        exit(1);
    }
 
 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
 
        fscanf(fl, "%s", data[i].fullname);
        fscanf(fl, "%i", data[i].group);
 
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
 
            fscanf(fl, "%i", data[i].firstMarks[j]);
            fscanf(fl, "%i", data[i].secondMarks[j]);
 
        }
 
    }
 
    fclose(fl);
 
    }
```

**файл table.txt**

```
Новикова Аделина Максимовна | 1151 |  5 2 3 1 2 |  1 2 1 3 2
Воронина Анна Леоновна | 2151 |  2 4 3 2 1 |  5 4 5 5 4
Медведева Елена Михайловна | 4452 |  4 2 1 3 4 |  2 4 5 2 1
Зайцев Пётр Миронович | 1148 |  2 3 4 5 1 |  5 2 1 5 5
Кочергин Алексей Семёнович | 3252 |  4 4 3 4 5 |  2 1 3 4 2
```

Всем привет! Задача: есть таблица, одна строка таблицы соответствует одному студенту и содержит следующие сведения: ФИО студента, номер группы, экзаменационные оценки за первый семестр, экзаменационные оценки за второй семестр.

Как мне считать в мои переменные структуры информацию из файла? Мои попытки безуспешны, надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: %s читает одно слово до пробела. А Вам нужно 3 слова или до палочки.

Comment: @KoVadim, и как сделать правильно? подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: ФИО где то так `fscanf(fl, "%[^|]", data[i].fullname);` можно и всю строку за раз прочитать, но с телефона мне это сложно написать. Под gcc/clang это должно работать. Под студией - надо проверить

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, работает, только еще вопрос как мне в файле переходить на следующую строку? `fscanf(fl, "\n");` в конце цикла заработает? И еще вопрос почему група и оценки не записываются в переменные?

Comment: группа и оценки не пишутся, потому что их  тоже нужно правильно прочитать. я вот такое придумал `struct Table t;
    sscanf(line, "%[^|]| %d | %d %d %d %d %d | %d %d %d %d %d", t.fullname, &t.group, &t.firstMarks[0], &t.firstMarks[1], &t.firstMarks[2], &t.firstMarks[3], &t.firstMarks[4], &t.secondMarks[0], &t.secondMarks[1], &t.secondMarks[2], &t.secondMarks[3], &t.secondMarks[4]);` А дальше можно просто читать ещё одну строку - оно само "перейдет".

Comment: @KoVadim, ого, спасибо, а зачем мы ставим ссылку перед t.group, t.firstMarks и т.д?

Comment: это не ссылка, это взятие адреса. Потому что scanf требует именно адреса переменной. В целом, код, который я привел - это чистый си, на плюсах оно чуточку по другому было бы. Но у Вас в коде так было, так что я так и писал.

Comment: @KoVadim, понял, а почему мы тогда t.fullname не брали адрес?

Comment: потому что fullname - это массив, а массив умеет притворятся (decay - деградировать) до указателя на первый свой элемент (некоторые говорят, что имя массива и есть указателем на первый элемент, но это немного неверная формулировка)

Comment: @KoVadim, ну t.firstMarks это же тоже массив xD

Comment: но я читаю ведь поэлементно. Да, вместо `&t.firstMarks[0]` можно было бы написать `t.firstMarks`, но так не стоит делать.

Comment: @KoVadim, хорошо, спасибо большое